# Loading og:image from assets in nuxt.config.js

Tags: nuxt.js

Is there a way to import an image and apply it to the og:image meta tag?
I have the following nuxt.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  head: {
    title: 'title name',
    meta: [
      // { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: process.env.BASE_URL + ogImage },
    ],
  },

  // ...
};
```

In a normal vue project this is done easily by using import:

```
import ogImage from '@/path/to/image.png';
```

However, import statements aren't available in nuxt.config.js and using require only results in loading the binary, instead of the asset path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Import statements are available in nuxt config since Nuxt 2.0. [See release notes](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v2.0.0). But that wont work since there no loaders and other things are in place yet.

You could set it in your layout file.

```
  import ogImage from '@/path/to/image.png';
  export default {
  head () {
    return {
      meta: [
        { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: this.BASE_URL+ ogImage }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Is there any way to enable these loaders, or should i have to wait untill nuxt officially supports it in their docu?

Comment: @user1213904 what u mean? This loaders enabled, but after nuxt config processed .

Comment: That if there is a way to enable usage of import statements, considering that they have made it available in nuxt 2.0. Or is the nuxt.config.js too limited by node.js reading it

Comment: @user1213904 u can use import in nuxt config in nuxt 2.0. But it wont give you path of image, it will give your content of image.

Comment: Ah ok now it's clear. Ill implement my options in the layout file!

Answer (score 8):

Save the image in static folder.

Create a publicRuntimeConfig in nuxt.config.js

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: { baseURL: process.env.NUXT_BASE_URL }
```

In the layout file add this:

```js
head() {
  return {
    title: 'PAGE TITLE',
    meta: [ { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: `${this.$config.baseURL}/logo.png` } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$config') 

Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to put the image to the og:image meta tag, you should move your image to the static folder because the static directory is directly mapped to the server root.
Here you can see the example for my setting.

[image]

After you run generate script, you can go to dist folder to open the index.html of your page, you will see the image url change to the root.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `og:image` should not use a relative url.

Answer (score 3):

Place your image in the static directory.

Then add the following to nuxt.config.js

```
head() {
  meta: [
  { charset: 'utf-8' },
  {
    hid: 'og:image',
    property: 'og:image',
    content: '/my_image.jpg',
  },
],
}
```